# C++/CLI Convert tracking handle into native pointer for Win32?

Tags: interop, c++-cli

The following code works when called from C#, but it seems inefficient because I take the data
from the managed world, make local native copies of it, call the Win32 function, and then copy
the data back into managed parameters, which are returned to the caller.

Is there a way to accomplish the following?

1) Pass the blittable UInt32 reference parameters directly to the Win32 call?  Please note
   that this Win32 call updates values, which I want to return to the caller (i.e. theSerialNumber)    In essense, can I pin_ptr the UInt32 reference parameter (i.e. theSerialNumber) as  LPDWORD that
   the native function can use and directly update its value?

2) Pass the StringBuilder buffers directly to the native function?  I imagine that I would
   need to set StringBuilder.Capacity = MAX_PATH+1;  But, I have no idea how to pin_ptr to
   its internal buffer, which the native function would use and update.

I have been experimenting, searching, and banging my head on these questions for hours, so
I really would appreciate your helP!

Thanks,

Mike

---

```
void MCVolume::VolumeInformation(String^ theRootPathName, 
            StringBuilder^% theVolumeName, 
            UInt32% theSerialNumber, 
            UInt32% theMaxComponentLength, 
            MEFileSystemFeature% theFileFlags, 
            StringBuilder^% theFileSystemName)
{

pin_ptr<const wchar_t> rootPathName = PtrToStringChars(theRootPathName);

wchar_t volumeName[MAX_PATH+1];
memset(volumeName, 0x0, MAX_PATH+1);
wchar_t fileSystemName[MAX_PATH+1];
memset(fileSystemName, 0x0, MAX_PATH+1);
DWORD serialNumber = 0;
DWORD fileFlags = 0;
DWORD maxComponentLength = 0;

//pin_ptr<DWORD> serialNumber = &theSerialNumber;

if (GetVolumeInformationW(rootPathName, 
            volumeName, 
            MAX_PATH+1,
            &serialNumber,
            &maxComponentLength, 
            &fileFlags, 
            fileSystemName,
            MAX_PATH+1) == false)                                   
{
    // Handle error
    throw gcnew Exception("GetVolumeInformationW failed.");
}

// Send back results...
theVolumeName = gcnew StringBuilder(marshal_as<String^>(volumeName));
theSerialNumber = serialNumber;
theMaxComponentLength = maxComponentLength;
theFileFlags = (MEFileSystemFeature) fileFlags;
theFileSystemName =  gcnew StringBuilder(marshal_as<String^>(fileSystemName));
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get rid of Marshalling both ways since both of the string types (managed string and native wchar*) are fundamentally different. Furthermore, GC needs to keep track of the managed resources that have been allocated and that's why you will always need to construct a `System::String^` object to be sent back to the managed world.

Comment: Not true, *you* don't have to construct the objects to be sent back to the managed world. Use P/Invoke and let the compiler do the work for you.

Comment: @taspeotis: Can you show an example. This is a rather new thing for me.

Comment: @Aamir - hi there, [this link](http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/archive/2005/06/20/414010.aspx) shows examples and situations where you would want to use P/Invoke from C++/CLI vs. managing (no pun intended) the Marshalling yourself.

Comment: Hi Everyone, Thank you for your comments...  Generally, I Marshal as I've done in this code, but I found references that seemed to indicate that I could do this kind of coding in a better manner.

Comment: After reading the link that Aamir mentioned, I see that what my research was hinting at was using P/Invoke from C++/CLI.  Although back in the deepest part of my memory, I knew that this could be done, I just never do it because I am in C++/CLI rather than C#.

Comment: For StringBuilder and Strings, I can see where P/Invoke can make the situation easier through automation.  However, I am still surprised that simple, blittable types like UInt32 cannot simply be passed into a native function.  For example, my managed function passes by reference a UInt32 theSerialNumber, which I hoped I could simply pin and pass on to the native function.  My research and experimenting has been unsuccessful in trying to do this without using P/Invoke. Is it impossible? Again, my general coding style is to use native for native and translate to Managed on function entry/exit.

Answer (score 0):

Just use P/Invoke from C++/CLI. See [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/archive/2005/06/20/414010.aspx) for more information.